# New roof has been installed

Tags: roof

The garage roof still sags. Decking is 8" boards. Some that were not replaced are cracked and or discolored. After removing shingles, roofer said straps and hangers needed. Roof still sags. He said that part of house had 3 layers of shingles, 2 in rest. Is he setting up excuse to not fix it? There had been no drip flashing. Gutters were nailed into shingles. Dip in roof was in middle, both sides. Gutter only on driveway side, so seems unlikely it was a factor. Roof was old. No vents in garage, 2 turbines on main attached house. Would osb or overlay have been worth huge price? What now?

Comment: Thickness of the decking and the span between the rafters/trusses is usually what matters.  The width of the decking boards has little to do with it.  The strength of the rafters is also important.

Comment: the title does not describe the problem ... please edit the title to match the rest of the post

Comment: `roofer said straps and hangers needed` ... were these replaced?

Comment: Wood "creeps" over time. See https://awc.org/faq/what-is-creep-and-how-can-i-address-it/. 3 layers of shingles is a lot of weight. Your builder could be describing how one part creeped under 3 layers versus another part under 2 layers. Are you talking about the roof sagging at the eaves where you can see waviness from the side between framing supports? Because OSB sheathing could cure that sort of sagging, but it wouldn't cure a sagging ridge beam, sagging rafters, or sagging truss chords.

Comment: You really need to be more specific in describing how the roof sags. If sagging is between framing elements, then OSB could have helped. If it's a full surface phenomenon that spans many framing elements, then OSB wouldn't have helped. I guess that you could have used temporary shoring to camber things a little and then fastened the OSB to lock in some of the recovered deflection, but I've never heard of somebody doing something like that outside of steel construction.

Answer (score 3):

Roofers install and repair roofs. They do not usually perform structural repairs, which seems to be the problem with your garage. Old garages were quite typically constructed with minimal structural strength in the roof framing, i.e. 2x4 rafters on 24" centers. These roofs will almost invariably develop sag over the years, especially when burdened with multi-layer roofing.